# How to pass data to php url without getting 404 error

Tags: php, url

I have an `index.php`in my website hosted at:

`https://example.com/api/redirect/index.php`

I want to make a url such that : `https://example.com/api/redirect/530` will not return an error 404 page.

Then I will use that number 530 in my `index.php` to do something.
How do I implement that url functionality ?

Edit: I am new to php and I don't even know what I am looking for here. Even a comment is greatly welcome!

i.e. How do I prevent a 404 error plus get that number 530, in the index.php to perform some operation?

Comment: what is the server that you use?

Comment: Actually, I did not know what I was looking for. Still, I did it! I used this `https://example.com/redirect/?var=530` and in my index.php i used `$var = $_GET['var']`. Now I can use the var in my code!

Comment: ok, nice. but if you want to use `/530` instead of `/?var=530` you can use `rewrite url` from your server. if you use Apache it's can set in `.htaccess`

Comment: oh, that'd be great! It is a shared hosting linux server. It does have .htaccess. Can you show me the rewrite rule, so that I could try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `.htaccess` in your `redirect` directory with the content below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can get the param in the index.php by `$_GET["var"]`

PS: make sure the rewrite module is activated. if you use ubuntu you run command `a2enmod rewrite` to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 is an error when site is not available.

You don't have a route for it perhaps,

or Your .htaccess file is wrong written

Comment: The index.php is accessible. I don't know how I could parse the url on index.php, without causing error 404. because, i am trying to do something like a controller, params thing here. But don't know how to

Comment: Ok but You are referring to https://example.com/api/redirect/503 in this case You should do something in Your htaccess file

Comment: OK, I did it! I used this `https://example.com/redirect/?var=530` and in my `index.php` i used `$var = $_GET['var']`. Now I can use the var in my code!